# What is the point of linking 2 source files instead of using a header file?

Tags: c

Why should I use another source code file to share code or a function between many programs and use the linker instead of using a header file only? (I read this in *Head First C* but I didn't understand what is the point of it)

Comment: Because the header files usually only contain the skeleton, the real logic is in the .c files (or, compiled, in the .o files)

Comment: @Ctx Do you mean that header files usually include declaration of function without its definition?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There are exceptions, but this is the rule.

Comment: The speed of the compiler is one reason. Imagine a library that has a million lines of code, you don't want to compile it every time you compile your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, header files should only be used to declare your functions/structs/classes.
The actual implementation should be created in a separate `.c` file which then can be built and exported as a binary along with the header.

Keeping the implementation in the header has many drawbacks.

1. Bigger footprint - the header size will be bigger since you have
   more symbols in it.
2. You cannot hide the implementation from the end-user.
3. The compile-time will be a lot larger since all code has to be processed every time it is included by the compiler.

Just to name a few. They might be many more reasons.

However, there are some cases when it is okay/better to include some logic in the header files.
For example for inline functions which may improve the runtime of the application while maintaining good code quality and/or templates in C++.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why isn't good to define a func in header

Comment: I want to ask you another question, I need link to source files to use defined functions and I link these file before I compile them. my question is how compile can get function definition from C Standard Library after I run my source file? (how does it know that I want source file of stdio.c after I run my program?)

Comment: It does not keep track of source files after the lib is built. The header contains information for the compiler and you are linking to the libraries which consist of binary files with instructions. When you install a compiler you get all of the core language libraries and the compiler knows where to find the files.
If you want to use a third-party library you have to specify it when you are building your program. I suggest picking a compiler(gcc for example) and read the documentation for it. Also, check what are `.so`/`.dll` and `.a` libs.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, header files contain *declarations*, like function signatures, while the function *definitions* (the actual source code) are located in separate source files.

Multiple files can include the same header file and share function declarations at compile time. But they also must share the source files (the files must be linked together) in order to have access to the function code at run time.

Comment: But I can declare and define a function in header file, Is it different from declare a function in header and define it in source file?

Comment: You *can* define a function in a header file, but it's inefficient and can cause multiple definition errors. See http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/47296/ (answer is for C++ but generally applies to C as well)

Comment: Thanks very much